# Whats the difference between # and $ in ELs in ADF

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, expression, el, oracle-adf

Have a really basic question on the difference between # and $ while evaluating ELs.
Ex.

```
<c:if test="#{bindings.value == true}">
```

and

```
<c:if test="${bindings.value == true}">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $ called Immediate evaluation syntax, while # called Deferred evaluation syntax
Check out this reference http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnahr